# Plugin custom edit page layout

Tags: plugin-development

Im making a plugin and have come to the stage where im making an edit form, for the plugin.

I would like the layout to look like this, with 2 columns and tabs above the left column.

[image: craft entry layout]

My, question is what is the best way to achive this? currently im using extending _layouts/cp in my template, the page look like this.

[image]

thanks for your help

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't appear there is an easy way to do this by extending that template. If you take a look at the template `templates/entries/_edit.html` you will see how the create/edit entry screen creates this view. It is extending `_layouts/cp`, but it's overriding the `main` Twig block to do some custom stuff. You can include the tabs in your main block like so:

```
{% block main %}
<div class="item" data-position="left" data-min-colspan="2" data-max-colspan="3">
    <div id="fields" class="pane">
        {% include "_includes/tabs" %}
    </div>
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: yes you want the .pane and .grid .item classes.