# Editorial workflow / custom status

Tags: workflow, status, editor, draft, pending

Currently my editors do not know when new content submitted by a user without publishing permissions is ready to be reviewed. The status of "disabled" could refer to an in-progress draft or a completed draft ready to be reviewed by an editor. There is no way the user can flag their article as ready and for this to be easily exposed to the editors in the admin panel.

How could this be addressed.

Comment: See a similar question here: *[Does Craft Have Publishing Workflow?](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/q/2533/5437)*

Answer (score 8, accepted):

One solution that comes to mind is to add your own custom status field (i.e. 'reviewStatus') as a drop-down menu (or checkbox perhaps if only one status). Then add this field as a column in your list view via a small plugin, using the new [modifyEntryTableAttributes](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/plugins/hooks-reference#modifyEntryTableAttributes) hook.

```
public function modifyEntryTableAttributes(&$attributes, $source)
{
    if ($source == 'section:3')
    {
        {# remove a column if desired #}
        //unset($attributes['expiryDate']);

        {# add a column #}
        $attributes['reviewStatus'] = Craft::t('Review Status');
    }
}
```

Might also check out [getEntryTableAttributeHtml](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/plugins/hooks-reference#getEntryTableAttributeHtml) hook (to customize the HTML display of that column), and [modifyEntrySortableAttributes](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/plugins/hooks-reference#modifyEntrySortableAttributes) hook (to add this field to the sort options).

To change the column display order you would need to unset all of the native attributes and reset them in the desired order (see [this answer](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/a/7051/784) for example).

Comment: Douglas, do you know if it is possible to add such a custom field to the right panel of the entry's edit view (with a plugin)? Or is this only possible for custom element types?

Comment: @carlcs Not that I'm aware of — but I've never looked into it.

Comment: Doesn't look like it is possible, I just had a look at templates/entries/_edit.html. Also found this question: ["Plugin custom edit page layout"](http://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/6748/plugin-custom-edit-page-layout).

Answer (score 4):

Douglas has posted a great suggestion about creating an additional custom field for "Status". But I think it's also worth mentioning Josh Crawford's great free plugin called [***Workflow***](https://github.com/engram-design/Workflow) which takes Craft's built-in permissions a step further with:

- User interface improvements, including a button to "Submit for Review"
- Email notifications to notify publishers that an entry is ready for review
- Entries become locked while they are awaiting review
- Extra events for hooking into the submission/publishing process with additional custom functionality

**Some screenshots:**

[image: Craft Workflow Plugin]

[image]

[image]

[image]

See https://github.com/engram-design/Workflow