# What does the 'modifyEntrySources' hook do?

Tags: plugin-development, hook

What does the [modifyEntrySources](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/plugins/hooks-reference#modifyEntrySources) hook do exactly, and when might one use it? Can someone help clarify this please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Source" is in the context of "where an element is pulling its data from".

The easiest example is with [Assets](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/assets), because they have easily defined Asset Sources settings portion of the control panel, but all elements (entries, tags, categories, users, etc.) have sources behind the scenes.

See the [CategorySources](https://github.com/pixelandtonic/CategorySources) plugin for an example of how it might be used (including a screenshot).

Comment: I guess my question is more specific in regards [this question](http://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/7044/editorial-workflow-custom-status) and whether modifying EntrySources would affect the status drop-down menu in the Entry List view in any way?

Comment: Hehe, this is exactly what I guessed (read hoped) 'modifyEntrySources' does when I read the release notes last week. 'modifyEntrySortableAttributes' is pretty much useless in most cases for me, without being able to define it per section (source?).

Comment: @Douglas the hook makes this possible: https://github.com/pixelandtonic/CategorySources/

Comment: @carlcs Thank you. That's the same link that brad posted above. But I did install it this time to see what it does. Still confused though. I looked at the code and can see that it added the categories to my entry sources, but how does that help me? No change to the CP that I can tell. Does this give me some new capability on the template side?

Comment: Ouups.. I should start reading SE post completely again. Totally missed Brad's last sentence, @Douglas!