# How to change the display order of columns in Entry List view?

Tags: plugin-development, control-panel, hook

When adding a custom column to an Entry List view using the [modifyEntryTableAttributes](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/plugins/hooks-reference#modifyEntryTableAttributes) hook, how would you also set the display order of columns?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to reorder the `$attributes` array to do this. You can do this in various ways, here is how I would do it depending on the position you wanted for the new column:

```php
public function modifyEntryTableAttributes(&$attributes, $source)
{
    if ($source == 'section:3')
    {
        // insert column in first position (using array_merge)
        $attributes = array_merge(array(['id'] => Craft::t('ID'), $attributes);

        // insert column in fourth position (using array_splice)
        array_splice($attributes, 3, 0, array('id' => Craft::t('ID')));  
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

As far as I can tell, you would need to unset all of the native columns and then reset them in the desired order.

```
public function modifyEntryTableAttributes(&$attributes, $source)
{
    if ($source == 'section:3')
    {
        // unset all column attributes
        unset($attributes['title']);
        unset($attributes['uri']);
        unset($attributes['postDate']);
        unset($attributes['expiryDate']);

        // set column attributes in the desired order
        $attributes['id'] = Craft::t('ID');
        $attributes['title'] = Craft::t('Title');
        $attributes['uri'] = Craft::t('URI');
        $attributes['postDate'] = Craft::t('Post Date');
        $attributes['expiryDate'] = Craft::t('Expiry Date');
    }
}
```