# Set status 'pending' on Guest Entry form

Tags: form, status, plugin-guestentries, pending

I'm using P&T's Guest Entries plugin along with my front end entry forms. All working fine except I want front end entries submitted with status 'pending'. Thought this would be pretty straightforward but something's not right. Atop my form I have:

```
<input type="hidden" name="action" value="guestEntries/saveEntry">
<input type="hidden" name="redirect" value="success">
<input type="hidden" name="enabled" value="1">
<input type="hidden" name="status" value="pending">
```

Anyone got statuses working in entry forms?

Answer (score 3):

The "status" on an entry isn't explicitly set like that. It is determined based on other properties of the entry. You will need to set these other criteria for the entry to appear as "pending".

`An entry is 'pending' if it is enabled and has Post and Expiration Dates in the future.`

More information on status' and the criteria can be found on the [docs](https://craftcms.com/docs/templating/craft.entries#status).

**UPDATE:** Depending on your use case, the following answer may be helpful: [Editorial workflow / custom status](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/7044/editorial-workflow-custom-status?rq=1)